# Enviar via Json dados para o controller

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

Estou tentando enviar via Ajax alguns dados do meu formulário. Neste formulário, tenho campos `inputs` normais e uma lista de fornecedores que eu previamente selecionei atraves do checkbox. Segue tela:

[image: Formulario]

Estou criando o objeto JSON e enviando por Ajax, mas a minha lista vem nula no *controller*.

Ajax:

```
var nomeUsuario = $("#NomeUsuario").val();
            var sobrenomeUsuario = $("#SobrenomeUsuario").val();
            var codigoUsuario = $("#CodigoUsuario").val();
            var emailUsuario = $("#EmailUsuario").val();

            //Busca todos os fornecedores selecionados
            var listCnpj = [];
            $('#datagrid tbody tr').filter(':has(:checkbox:checked)').each(function () {
                var elem = $(this)[0];
                listCnpj.push("Codigocnpj:" + elem.cells[0].innerHTML);
            });

            // build json object
            var squirrel = {
                NomeUsuario: nomeUsuario,
                SobrenomeUsuario: sobrenomeUsuario,
                CodigoUsuario: codigoUsuario,
                EmailUsuario: emailUsuario,
                ListaFornecedorViewModels: [listCnpj]
            };
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'Gravar',
                data: squirrel,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {

                },
                error: function (data) {

                    alert('Error' + data);
                }
            });
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Gravar(UsuarioViewModel usuarioViewModel)
    {
        JsonResult json = new JsonResult();
        return json;

    }
```

E a minha model:

```
public class UsuarioViewModel {

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CodigoUsuario { get; set; }
    public string NomeUsuario { get; set; }
    public string SobrenomeUsuario { get; set; }
    public string SenhaUsuario { get; set; }
    public string EmailUsuario { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public string Prontuario { get; set; }
    public string FornecedorBusca { get; set; }
    public List<Fornecedor> ListaFornecedorViewModels { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Já tentou verificar o inspetor do seu browser para conferir como a requisição está sendo montada?

Comment: Ja sim Cigano... Esta indo com os dados:

A lista fica assim: listCnpj = ["{'Codigocnpj' : '85.558.272/0001-40','RazaoSocial' : '', 'Municipio' : '' }", "{'Codigocnpj' : '85.558.272/0001-70','RazaoSocial' : '' , 'Municipio' : '' }]

Comment: Tenta enviar a lista direto, ao invés de ListaFornecedorViewModels: [listCnpj] envia ListaFornecedorViewModels: listCnpj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Já tive esse problema, passa o parâmetro como sendo uma `string JSON`:

No teu `Ajax` usa isso:

```
var dataJson = JSON.stringify(squirrel);

 $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'Gravar',
                data: { modelo: dataJson },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {

                },
                error: function (data) {

                    alert('Error' + data);
                }
            });
```

Renomeia o parametro do teu method no controller p/ string:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Gravar(string modelo)
    {
        JsonResult json = new JsonResult();
        return json;
    }
```

Essa solução deverá funcionar.